# Java Link list error message when executed @number

Tags: java, collections

Whenever i run the method, i get an error which comes with as numbers

The following is what i have as my code.

```
public String getAccount()
{
   String s = "Listing the accounts";
    for(List l:lists)
     s+=" "+list.toString;
   Return s;
}
```

I get the following when i run this method:

> List@some numbers

For the List class, i just have a constructor which appoints parsed variables into local variables.

DOes someone know what this means?

Comment: `lists` and `list` aren't defined in your code, so we have no idea what they are. And you're not using your `l` variable.

Comment: How are you initializing the `lists` variable?

Comment: Where what you defined `list`? Also `Return s` will not compile, it should be `return s`.

Comment: Im initialising  as follows:

private LinkedList<List> lists = new LinkedList<List>();

Comment: @Benji: What is the `List` type here?

Answer (score 2):

This means that you haven't overridden the `toString` method in your (apparently) custom `List` class. The default implementation ([`Object.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)) displays output like you show above:

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

You should override `toString` in your custom classes, in order to provide the desired output.

Comment: @Benji, as I wrote above, override `toString` to produce the desired output. E.g. by iterating through the list members and printing each. I have no idea what you want to see as output, so I can't give you more specific advice.